# Cómo obtener el valor de una posición en un arreglo en C++?

Tags: c++, array

Buen día
Estoy entrenando mi lógica de programación como principiante.
En el programa en el que estoy trabajando pido el tamaño de mi arreglo y los datos para llenar cada posición o espacio.

Lo que aún no puedo lograr es: mostrar el dato guardado en la posición que yo quiera ejemplo: si yo quiero que solo me muestre el valor de la poción 2 me muestre el dato que ya guarde ahí.

También al contrario si le doy un valor que me diga en qué posición esta y si está repetido en otra posición.

Talvez sea simple pero aún no logro hacerlo. De antemano muchas gracias a quien corresponda

Comment: Para mostrar el dato guardado en una posición:
· https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_arrays.asp
Para buscar un valor en un array o ver si está repetido, tienes que recorrerlo y luego comparar sus valores:
 · https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/06/20/buscar-elemento-arreglo-cpp/

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver el código no puedo saber qué tipo de formación<sup>1</sup> estás usando, pero en general tanto si se trata de una formación en el *stack* como si se trata de un `std::vector` o si es una formación gestionada por un puntero inteligente el comportamiento es el mismo:

```
int *Formacion = new int[tamanyo];
std::vector<int> Vector(tamanyo);
auto Puntero_inteligente = std::make_unique<int[]>(tamanyo);

// dato guardado en la posición que yo quiera…
Formacion[2] = 42;
Vector[2] = 42;
Puntero_inteligente[2] = 42;

// muestre el valor de la poción 2…
std::cout << Formacion[2] << '\n'
          << Vector[2] << '\n'
          << Puntero_inteligente[2] << '\n';
```

Para buscar valores puedes usar las utilidades de la librería estándar, como `std::find` de la cabecera `<algorithm>`:

```
template <typename iterador>
void busca_dato_en(int dato, const iterador inicio, const iterador fin)
{
    std::cout << "Dato " << dato;
    if (auto encontrado = std::find(inicio, fin, dato); encontrado != fin)
        std::cout << " encontrado en posicion " << std::distance(inicio, encontrado) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << " no encontrado\n";
};

// Dato 42 encontrado en posicion 2
busca_dato_en(42, Formacion, Formacion + tamanyo);
// Dato 42 encontrado en posicion 2
busca_dato_en(42, Vector.begin(), Vector.end());
// Dato 50 no encontrado
busca_dato_en(50, Puntero_inteligente.get(), Puntero_inteligente.get() + tamanyo);
```

Para saber si un valor está repetido, puedes contarlo con la utilidad `std::count` de la cabecera `<algorithm>` (asumiendo un tamaño de 20):

```
template <typename iterador>
void cuenta_dato_en(int dato, const iterador inicio, const iterador fin)
{
    std::cout << "Dato " << dato << " esta " << std::count(inicio, fin, dato) << " veces en los datos\n";
};

// Dato 42 esta 1 veces en los datos
cuenta_dato_en(42, Formacion, Formacion + tamanyo);
// Dato 0 esta 19 veces en los datos
cuenta_dato_en(0, Vector.begin(), Vector.end());
// Dato 50 esta 0 veces en los datos
cuenta_dato_en(50, Puntero_inteligente.get(), Puntero_inteligente.get() + tamanyo);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVPBbtNAED3bXzGEQx2SVpFVLnWSE@LMiUsaRdv1xKywZ413XIhQfx0za7uOmwTRA9x237735s14rMvyWueKsqZ5a0jndYqwNNZxhapYh0fsETXbaowUWNjqMEZUntnK8BcRhoxFmSsWlA8lkioQDGOlUm/yaE0KD7XTapcqtjukyBCDP89BW3I8kMGQ0eYc3huahj/DwHF6d6dtzbBcwuSDOMDEH71XEgZmD5GqBUQSA/ZaWEErEoc0enaXy7zVTJMx9c2qKxSc1BlzkKC0zttQV7qlpsaxIo1DhaNi6klX93Ql@TB3eO5O47z3NEnCp@Q1I9U1Ev/fmfbtS3OjZoVLfGGWHVlWB50fU25di7uhJZ@wUIaivq5io7tU@KP0ORlYFYoO/qvFC1EEHnv30VaFaie@AsLvnrjpidukb6Db2KU8reFze456ylQo7VJ8kthY2Z1wMDeZDA@ft6NQX3FXk/lWo7fYbNcjdRgMATbxViS3sVh2RUbABfvjaxi8/AFu4zkMrqMjzGAU@1zTVb15wMyPcbijLPf0XPF@Mb/U9U2G7MV/fHqRIgxOFu112U9Ei79nP1H8o/Ap5ihfYnvM6dEKua4IZMeemuaX3ucqc8217MJKz2ax@g0)</kbd>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No estás especificando qué tipo de arreglo usas ni estás proporcionando código de referencia, según las reglas tienes que tratar de resolver el problema por tu cuenta, no te proporcionaré los métodos de búsqueda porque depende del tipo de arreglo y es tu deber intentarlo primero.
Viendo que eres principiante seguro no usas herramientas de la std, así que yendo a lo tradicional de c++ :

```
int* vector = nullptr;
int tamano = 5;

vector = new int[tamano];
```

Aquí, un puntero tipo int* al que le asignamos un valor nullptr, esto por buenas prácticas y posibles futuras comprobaciones. Luego, con la variable tamano, puedes guardar cualquier dígito y, en tiempo de ejecución (puedes usar cout y cin para preguntar el tamaño y capturar el dígito digitado), variar el tamaño del vector. Al final, le asignamos a vector la dirección de memoria devuelta por el operador new. En vector, tendremos la primera dirección de memoria del arreglo creado por new.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {
vector[i] = i;
}

for (int j = 0; j < tamano; j++) {
std::cout << vector[j] << "\n";
}

delete[] vector;
```

Ahora, para poder ingresar valores, usas el operador [ ], que en este caso usarás con números enteros positivos para acceder a las diferentes posiciones del arreglo, tanto para guardar como para leer datos. El primer for guarda en las posiciones 0-4 los valores que toma i; luego, para el segundo for, accedemos a las diferentes posiciones con la variable j y las imprimimos en pantalla.